# Stellar.js responsiveness without resizing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image, stellar.js

Okay this is a rather complicated setup/question so I will try to explain it as clear as possible. Right now stellar parallax is working great on my site with no issues whatsoever. this was accomplished by setting the responsive property in stellar.js to true which makes it so that the background image follows the div when you resize the window. Because the issue before was that resizing the window was bad because stellar vertically aligns the background images in a certain way so if you resized the window the div in question might end up in an area where the background is repeating or in an empty spot(if you had no repeat on), it just wouldnt be aligned with the background image anymore. Responsiveness=true fixed this.

However here is the new issue. I have a section on my website where 3 divs are set to display: none by default. 3 buttons, respectively, toggle their display. Toggling their display makes their parent div much longer therefore pushing the rest of the content of the page further down. This pushes the stellar divs out of position with their background images again and i can see areas where the image repeats or are blank(if you have no repeat). However if you resize the window after you toggled the three hidden divs, the stellar divs will automatically fix itself and realign the images as a result of it picking up the responsiveness. I was wondering if there was anyway perhaps I could make toggling the hidden divs trigger this realignment without the user having to resize the window(he/she wouldnt know he/she had to anyway)?

Perhaps a way to refresh a specific part of the page(the stellar divs)? Or perhaps a function to resize the window by like a pixel or even 0 pixels just to trigger the responsiveness?

Thanks in advance, I hope everything makes sense.